# Two finite-rank projections P and Q, if $\|P - Q\| < 1$, then rank $P$ = rank $Q$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, projection

Let $P, Q \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ be two finite-rank projections. If $\|P - Q\| < 1$, then rank $P$ = rank $Q$.

**My attempt:**

If $P$ has rank of $n$, then $Px=\sum_1^n \hat x_j (\ell, x)$, where $\hat x_j$ is a set of orthonormal basis.

I want to prove by contradiction. Suppose rank $P$ > rank $Q$, then somehow $\|P-Q\| >= 1$.

I fail to use the property $P,Q$ are projections ($P^2x = Px$). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this a Hilbert space?

Comment: It doesn't specify.

Comment: I think $X$ is more likely to be Banach space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Since $||P-Q||<1$, the operator $I + (P-Q)$ is invertible. Therefore, for every 
$y \in X$ there exists $x \in X$ so that 
$x + (P-Q) x = y$, or $(x-Qx) + Px = y$.

It follows that $\ker Q + \operatorname{im} P = X$ and so 
rank $Q \le$ rank $P$.

$\bf{Added:}$

From the equation above we have $Qy = Q Px$. Therefore, the map $Q\colon \operatorname{im} P \to \operatorname{im} Q$ is surjective. So  rank $Q \le$ rank $P$.

For the invertibility of $I + (P-Q)$, check [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series#Example).

Comment: Could you please give me more details? Why is I+(P-Q) invertible? And how it follows that $ker Q + im P = X$? And Why $rank Q \leq rank P$ from this?

Comment: @baNv: check out the added details..

Answer (score 1):

If say rank$(P) > $rank$(Q)$, you can find a nonzero element $x$ of the range of $P$ which is orthogonal to the range of $Q$. For in terms of basis elements of $Q$ the statement that  $<x,y>$   $= 0$ for all $y$ in $Q$ reduces to an equation of rank$(Q)$ variables.
If rank$(P) >$ rank$(Q)$ then there will be a nonzero solution.

In this situation, $(P - Q)x = Px - Qx  = Px - 0 = x$. Thus $||P - Q|| \geq 1$.

Comment: How do we draw the conclusion that $Qx=0$?

Comment: Since the range of $Q$ is a closed subspace of your Hilbert space, every vector $v$ can uniquely be written as $v = v_1 + v_2$ where $v_1$ is in the range of $Q$ and $v_2$ is in the orthogonal space. The projection $Q$ takes $v$ to $v_1$. In the case at hand $x = v = v_2$ and $v_1 = 0$.

Comment: How do you know it is a Hilbert space?

Comment: Because he referred to orthonormal bases and projections, I assumed the problem was in the context of Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Actually, the original problem doesn't specify the space. My attempt may be wrong. Will that falsify the proof?

Comment: @baNv You would need a different proof if $X$ is more general than a Hilbert space. What were you told about $X$?

Comment: Nothing. It just says exactly as I write in the description.

Comment: Where did you find the problem?

Comment: It's on the homework. I guess it's more likely to be Banach space.

Comment: I believe this proof idea works with $X$ being a Banach Space and $P$ and $Q$ viewed purely as finite-rank idempotent operators (which per the phrasing in the problem is exactly what we have).